# SQL Statement fails, even if there are entities in the db

Tags: java, sql, eclipse, hsqldb

I have a table called Produkt and in this table there are several products called test.

When I want to do that code:

```
public Produkt findByName(String name) throws SQLException{
    log.error("Enter findByName with parameters: " + name);
    PreparedStatement ps;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    String query = "SELECT * FROM Produkt WHERE name=" + name;
    ps=hsqlmanager.getConnection().prepareStatement(query);
    rs = ps.executeQuery();
    ps.close();
    if(rs.next()) return(new Produkt(rs));
    else return(null);
}
```

it always gives me an sql error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: user
lacks privilege or object not found: TEST   at
org.hsqldb.jdbc.Util.sqlException(Unknown Source)   at
org.hsqldb.jdbc.Util.sqlException(Unknown Source)   at
org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCPreparedStatement.<init>(Unknown Source)    at
org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCConnection.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)     at
dao.DAOProdukt.findByName(DAOProdukt.java:157)  at
dao.test_produkt_dao.main(test_produkt_dao.java:23)
```

why? i appreaciate your answer!!!

**UPDATE:**

Why are the PS incorrectly used? Pls tell me so that I can learn from that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're generating an invalid SQL statement, with no quotes around your `name` parameter

```
String query = "SELECT * FROM Produkt WHERE name='" + name + "'";
                                                 ^--      ^^^^^^
```

Comment: It also looks like OP is incorrectly using Prepared Statements.

Comment: This should really be replaced by `"SELECT * FROM Produkt WHERE name=?" and a call to `setString()`.

Comment: why are my prepared statement incorrectly used? Pls tell me ,so that I can learn!

Comment: This is just inviting a SQL injection attack. Prepared statements FTW.

Answer (score 1):

You should use PreparedStatements correctly to prevent SQL injection. It also writes the quotes around the parameters, where it is neccessary.

```
String query = "SELECT * FROM Produkt WHERE name=?";
PreparedStatement ps=hsqlmanager.getConnection().prepareStatement(query);
ps.setString(1, name);
```

Comment: how could my version lead to sql injection?

Comment: @maximus: Well your current version wouldn't work at all as there's no quoting - but see http://bobbytables.com for more information about SQL injection, and how it takes place. (Or do some general research - just searching for sql injection attacks will get you a lot of hits explaining the problem.)

Answer (score 1):

You should not be including the value within your SQL at all. Doing so invites a SQL injection attack unless you're *very* careful with quoting. (For non-string values, it also introduces a potentially-incorrect string conversion, too. Oh, and it mixes code with data, effectively. Just say "No" to variable values in SQL...)

Instead, use a `PreparedStatement` and a parameter, then set the value of the parameter to the name you're looking for. For example:

```
String query = "SELECT * FROM Produkt WHERE name = ?";
PreparedStatement ps = hsqlmanager.getConnection().prepareStatement(query);
ps.setString(1, name);
ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
```

Note that you should also have `close()` statements in `finally` blocks to avoid leaking resources if an exception is thrown.

See the [Data Access and Change](http://hsqldb.org/doc/guide/dataaccess-chapt.html#dac_jdbc_parameters) part of the HSQLDB user guide for HSQLDB-specific details, or the [JDBC tutorial on prepared statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) for more generic information.

Comment: and how can i get the name into the query? pls explain that part!